# s3cmd: how to copy files from local to S3 bucket with existing structure

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to copy files with `s3cmd` to a bucket with an existing folder structure. Both structures already exist both on local dev machine and in the bucket.

The folders structure is as follows `/dir2/`

```
dir2/
  00001/
  00002/
  00003/
  ...
```

Problem is when I'm trying to copy the info from my local machine to the bucket as follows

```
s3cmd put --acl-public --recursive --verbose /home/user/dir1/dir2/ s3://my.bucket/assets/dir1/dir2/
```

I'm getting the following output.

```
INFO: Compiling list of local files...
INFO: Applying --exclude/--include
INFO: Summary: 0 local files to upload
```

Looks like since the folders already exists on the bucket, s3cmd avoid copying the files from local machine beside the fact that they're not on the bucket (just the folders and other, different named files).

Any idea how to copy the files even when there's an existing sub-folder structure inside?

Comment: Could you just pipe `find` output to `s3cmd`?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the trick here is to add `--include *` to the flags.

Answer (score 0):

Command `s3cmd sync` maybe can be helpful

```
s3cmd sync  my-local-dir/ s3://my-test-bucket
```

And if needed you can exclude some files like below:

```
s3cmd sync  my-local-dir/ --exclude '*.txt' s3://my-test-bucket
```

And if you need to change permissions to Public/Private for all files you can run the command below:

```
s3cmd setacl s3://my-test-bucket --acl-public --recursive
s3cmd setacl s3://my-test-bucket --acl-private --recursive
```