# How to copy files on unix shell using wildcards

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to copy some files into existing folders. This is an example of the schema

```
# origin 
/home/user/myfiles/folder1/group1/1.jpg
/home/user/myfiles/folder1/group1/2.jpg
/home/user/myfiles/folder1/group2/1.jpg
/home/user/myfiles/folder1/group2/2.jpg
/home/user/myfiles/folder2/group1/1.jpg
/home/user/myfiles/folder2/group1/2.jpg
/home/user/myfiles/folder2/group2/1.jpg
/home/user/myfiles/folder2/group2/2.jpg
```

The destination folder schema already exists, its just the origin files (jpgs) that are not there.

My question is how to do this?

I would like to end up with something like below, but this is not working. Maybe I should include regex in the query to separate asterisk into values and use as origin/destination?

```
 cp /home/user/myfiles/*/*/*.jpg  /home2/user/myfiles/*/*/*.jpg
```

My original intend is to use this copying schema on my unanswered question:  [s3cmd: how to copy files from local to S3 bucket with existing structure](https://superuser.com/questions/453568/s3cmd-how-to-copy-files-from-local-to-s3-bucket-with-existing-structure) as a possible solution.

Comment: Are the destination folders completely empty? If so just delete them and copy files and directory structure. Also, the shell expansion of the second set of asterixes is your problem.

Comment: They're not. They have other type of files that I still need.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last sentence?

Comment: I can, but I am still trying to wrap my head around what your precise goal is. The cp command has the same source and destination. The s3cmd question identified local dev and remote s3 site, that I could understand. But the current question seems to be a NOP.  (Granted, that might be because I am sleepy).

Comment: @Hennes Sorry for misleading you, just fixed the question. The dest should be different than origin!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU cp you can use the `--parents` option, like this:

```
cd /home/user/myfiles ; cp --parents */*/*.jpg /home2/user/myfiles/
```

You have to `cd` first because if you do `cp --parents /home/user/myfiles/...` it will create those parents too, and you'll end up with `/home2/user/myfiles/home/parents/myfiles/`.

If you need a non-GNUish answer, the traditional unix method would be tar over a pipe.

```
cd /home/user/myfiles ; tar cf - */*/*.jpg | ( cd /home2/user/myfiles ; tar xf - )
```

The second `cd` is in a subshell with the second tar, so that's where the files get extracted. The tarball itself is created, sent over the pipe, and extracted all at the same time. Add a `v` flag to one of the tars if you want progress reporting.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
for i in `find /home/user/myfiles/folder1 -print`; do 
  if [ ! -d $i ]; 
    then filePath=`echo $i | cut -f 4- -d"/"`; 
         cp $i /home/user/myfiles/folder2/$filePath; 
  fi; 
done
```

Basically, I am extracting the part of the filename that is going to change between the two folders, and then issuing a copy command.

Notice the "cut -f **4-**" above - it gets the fields from the 4th one onwards. You can change the number as per your wish

Perhaps even `basename` or a simpler command exists... but this will do for now :)